# Error al crear dos llaves foraneas con migraciones

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo este problema al intentar generar esta tabla, haciendo referencia a dos llaves foraneas, primero cree las tablas que son areas y sucursal,una ves migradas y generadas en la base de datos genero la tabla empleados, pero me sale este error, tambien intente hacerlo con sintaxis de sql pero me sale el mismo error, no se que estoy haciendo mal.
añexo el codigo de la migracion y el error

este es mi error y anexo todo mi codigo de migraciones
[image: Error de Consola]

esta es la tabla que me da error al migrar

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Empleado extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empleado', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id_empleado');
            $table->String('alias');
            $table->String('carrera');
            $table->String('area');
            $table->String('clave');
            $table->String('direccion');
            $table->String('telefono');
            $table->String('conyuge');
            $table->String('hijos');
            $table->String('transporte');
            $table->String('tiempo');
            $table->String('escuela');
            $table->String('comentarios');
            $table->Integer('ida');
            $table->Integer('ids');
            $table->foreign('ida')->references('ida')->on('area');
            $table->foreign('ids')->references('idsucursal')->on('sucursal');
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

las dos tablas que creo primero, areas

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Area extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('area', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('ida');
            $table->string('sucursal');
            $table->string('direccion');
            $table->string('importancia');
            $table->integer('cp');
            $table->string('proveedor');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Esta tabla es de sucursal

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Sucursal extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::create('sucursal', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('ids');
            $table->string('sucursal');
            $table->string('direccion');
            $table->string('importancia');
            $table->integer('cp');
            $table->string('proveedor');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: estoy usando la version 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Una llave foránea debe tener las siguientes características:

- Corresponder al tipo de dato de la llave primaria vinculada
- No permitir valores con signo
- Corresponder la longitud

Dado eso entonces en la migración debemos usar lo siguiente:

```
unsignedInteger()
```

Quedando de está forma [(*ejemplo tomado de la doc.*)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

```
 Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

     $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
  });
```

Comment: Me sigue mandando el error cuando intento añadir las dos llaves foráneas, con una sola llave si lo crea, pero al añadir la segunda ya me da el error

Comment: si, primero creo las dos primeras tablas que es areas y sucursal  al final nadamas migro la tabla empleados, y es cuando me da error

Answer (score 0):

a mi también me pasó el problema de querer integras dos llaves foraneas en una misma tabla soy novato en el campo llevo 2 meses viendo como es todo esto encontré esta solución:
1)error: es porque el tipo de dato id es diferente al tipo de dato que estamos referenciando
*ejemplo1 de laravel: `$table->id(); id hace referencia al tipo de dato bigIncrements`

si es así debemos referenciarlo de esta manera:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
```

está fué mi solución para agregar 2 o mas llaves foranes en conclusion si nuestro dato es bigIncrements entonces debemos referenciarlo con unsignedBigInteger.

*ejemplo 2: en tu caso tu tipo de dato es increments por lo tanto debemos referenciarlo con integer, pero debemos agregar los siguientes parametros:

```
$table->integer('ids_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
$table->foreign('ids_id')->references('ids')->on('sucursal')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
```

NOTA IMPORTANTE: TE RECOMIENDO MIGRAR LAS TABLAS EN PRURAL YA QUE ELOQUENT EN LOS MODELOS DETECTA AUTOMATICAMENTE LAS TABLAS EN PRURAL, es decir que si tu tabla es sucursal en el modelo entonces en tu migracion debe ir como sucursals ya que ELOCUENT BUSCA EL NOMBRE DE LA TABLA CON UNA "s" al final.